# Не могу подключить библиотеку к react-native + type script

Tags: typescript, импорт, react-native

Есть проект на react native 0.42.0 и к нему прикручен type script 2.3.2. После установки библиотеки https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper и добавления типизации www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native-swiper. При попытке подключить библиотеку, способом

```
import * as Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
```

как указанно в ts документации выдает ошибку в самом приложении

> com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: {"stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?.

Также пробовал подключить

```
const Swiper = require('react-native-swiper');
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
```

ts компилит нормально но react native не может запустить приложение.
Не могу понять как подключить чтобы работало?

Answer (score 0):

Я понял свою ошибку. Дело было в названии папки в которой находился проект ( RN042_TS ). После пересборки в другой папке (testReactNative) и изменение названия проекта в packaje.json - начало работать обычный import. Ура!